# Reverse engineer Oracle database in visio

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Trying to reverse engineer tables added into a database but when i connect, I get strange Chinese symbols with a lot of apex stuff.

[image]

I dont see anywhere the tables that i added, what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check the character set the database is configured to support, then check Visio to see if it's using the same set. Also I think character sets can be configured on a per table basis so if some tables are fine and the new ones are not, take a look at the table character set too.